# apache configuration for react-router with browserHistory and baseName subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, react-router

My application is in a subdirectory of the main web site.  I have implemented basename and browserHistory and put the following recommended apache rewrite code into .htaccess in the app folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

This recommended apache rewrite works to return browserHistory URLs to the application index.html.  For some reason (see below), it does not find the "style.css" and "brundle.js" that are EMBEDDED in the index page HTML.  The only thing that I can see that I have different in the example .htaccess file is that I have a RewriteBase value of "/react_librivox_search" because my application is in that subfolder of the site.

```
RewriteBase /react_librivox_search
```

I have tested using various different beginning and ending slashes for paths and files in .htaccess, and the problem is not that.

The problem seems to be that the react application is setting a GET value for the files that includes a part of the PATH variable that is supposedly only a part of the react-router definition:

```
<Route path="/book/:id" component={BookDataDisplay}/>
```

Note that the additional path segment "/book/" is being appended to the base URL, and when files are not found in THAT directory (which does not really exist), the server returns "index.html" for the missing files, which accounts for the mime-type error for the librivox_search.css file and the "<" error for the bundle.js file.

```
The stylesheet http://jstest.dd:8083/react_librivox_search/book/librivox_search.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.       librivox_search.css (embedded in index.html)

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'       bundle.js (embedded in index.html)
```

The same unexpected addition of "book" to the URL is at work here as well. Neither of the embedded index.html files is in that subdirectory. But I want to maintain that "book" in the path, since it identifies what KIND of data is being passed to the route . . . which distinquishes it from other kinds of data.  I just do not want to have it sent to the SERVER (but perhaps that cannot be avoided), since the actual index.html embedded files are not there.

I suppose rewriting "/react_librivox_search/book" as "/react_librivxo_search" might work, but it seems to be a hacky way to go about it.  And I don't want to have to put duplicate bundle.js files in multiple directories (that works, but 
what a maintenance nightmare THAT would be, and no doubt bad practice).

Or is it recommended to put a separate .htaccess in a REAL "book" subfolder that returns "librivox_search.css" and "bundle.js" (in the base directory) depending on the file request?